# Preventing editing of / obscuring parameters in URLs

Tags: php, url

I have list of rows that I have fetched using `mysql_fetch_array()`. Now I have created hyperlink of these values but problem is I don't want to send id through hyperlink. That is if item onl ist is clicked it navigate to `view.php` but values are send through hidden variable.

Is there any way to do so? If not how can I send values through addressbar such that values are not edited by viewer? that is id is not edited by user...

Comment: Do try to ensure you have a meaningful title to your questions.  It is all people have to go on unless they go to the effort of reading your whole question.  I have edited it to something more suitable for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want to either a.) obfuscate the ids or b.) restrict the ids a user can view.

For achieving the former, you could generate a random hash for each entry in the database that is much longer than the id and very hard to guess (`hash('sha512', time() + $row['id'])`). You can than use these unique hashes instead of the ids in your links.

The other approach depends highly on your application: you can keep track of the ids that you provided to the user in your session and deny the page request (send an [HTTP 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) response) if the id was not in his list. An attacker might call other pages first, though (if this is possible in your application), to fill this link list in his session.

Either way, you are not guaranteed to succeed, but you can make the attack *much* harder.

The only method of achieving your goal for sure is to force your users to log in and decide who can see which object per user (again, if this is possible in your application).

Comment: Thanks Soulmerge : Thanks for your solution to my doubts. Well I am beginner with php. Can you make a short example how to implement `hash function` and retrieve respective `id` in `view.php` page.

Comment: `hash` is a builtin PHP function, you just need to check if the `SHA512` algorithm is available in your machine. You can chose another one to your liking, even if it is, of course.

Comment: On p_action page
    `<a href="p_view.php?title=<?= hash('sha512', time() + $row['p_id'])]?>"><?=$row['p_name'] ?></a>`

Now p_view.php how can I get decrypt values...

Comment: Hash algorithms are not reversible, you would need to store them in your database, as an additional unique index.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it.

I mean, ID or some unique value simply must be sent to tell the server what are you requesting. That is simple logic.

However, to make "changing value" a little harder, you can use AJAX. Request using ID is still sent, but in the background and normal user won't notice anything.
Beware, someone with a little technical knowledge will be able to investigate requests and that's done by simply using Firebug or some other dev tool, so you'r still no good.

If you think you could benefit from such a thing, believe me, you won't. This is not the way to handle the security, if that was your intention.

Comment: uh, you're right, I've made that mistake a hundred times before ^^ ty, fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

To make this a little harder, you can encrypt the ID and decrypt it once you get it on the view.php, this way it becomes difficult to predict and mess around with. For instance something like the youtube video urls